Do increasing the number of variables in a function leads us to new dimensions in space.
Let $f(x) = x^2$ then $y=x^2$ here the values of $x$ gives the solution of $y$ in $Y$-axis means the graph so forming will be in second dimension.
Similarly if $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ then $z=x^2+y^2$ here the input values of $x$ and $y$ give the solution of $z$ in $Z$-axis means the graph this function will be in third dimension.
Similarly can we say that $f(x, y, z) = x^2 +y^2+ z^2$ then
$q = x^2+y^2+z^2$ here the input values of $x$, $y$, $z$ give the solution of $q$ in fourth axis which is perpendicular to our $3$ axes i.e graph of this function will be in fourth dimension.
And can we say that as we increase the variables in a function it will give rise to new dimensions in space?

Are you asking whether the graph of a real-valued function of $n$ real variables lies in $(n+1)$-dimensional space? If so, then yes, as if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, then its graph can be identified with the set ${(x_1,\dots,x_n,f(x_1,\dots,x_n)) : (x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Another issue worth noting is that if you are in 2D then the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ represents a circle, while if you are in 3D the exact same equation represents a vertical cylinder as z is unspecified. So you do not need $z=..$ to create a 3D object.

The $n$-dimensional Cartesian space $\mathbb R^n$ is a well-established tool in mathematics. Each of its points is an $n$-tuple of real numbers $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, generalizing ordered pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ and ordered triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. A real valued function whose domain is $\mathbb R^n$ can be expressed as $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, and its graph can, as you have guessed, be expressed as a subset of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ by adding one more coordinate representing the "dependent" variable.
All of this is standard fare in, say, an advanced calculus course or an elementary topology course.
It is also standard in applications to physical sciences. In physics, for example, the 4-dimensional space-time of special relativity is modelled mathematically by using $\mathbb R^4$ with coordinates $(x,y,z,t)$ where $t$ represents the time coordinate.

More variables needn't mean more dimensions... well,depends on what you mean by 'dimension'. The n-sphere $S^n$ is $n$-'dimensional' but exists in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ space.
For example, the 1-sphere, aka the circle is 1-dimensional but w/ 2 variables $x^2+y^2=1$ (let's say unit) and indeed exists in 2D space.
Also, the 2-sphere, aka the sphere is 2-dimensional but w/ 3 variables $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ (again, let's say unit) and indeed exists in 3D space.
However, the entire real line $\mathbb R$ is just 1 variable $y=0$ (well technically if you have an 'equation', then it's like $y=0x^0$, and it's in 2D space just like the circle, etc).
So... do you consider the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ to be '1-dimensional' just like the real line $\mathbb R$ ?
